# Implement Google Places Api in Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am first time implementing google spaces autocomplete search in the E-commerce website. I am implementing help with http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Places-AutoComplete-example-without-using-Maps.aspx.

When i am using In HTML page, It is working correctly.

```js
    var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {  
  var input = document.getElementById('id_address');
  var options = {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'in'
    }
  };

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
          document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
          
alert(place.address_components[i].long_name);
          
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="id_address" type="text" value="" />
<div id="postal_code"></div>
```

But when i am implementing same thing in my project then it is showing some error in console of browser.

**SCREEN SHOT:**
[image]

[image]

In browser showing some icon and disable to search.
I can't understand what is the issue. Because in HTML file or jsfiddle working fine. But not working in website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the errors you are getting, it looks like you should:

1. remove `sensor=false&` from `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>`. Having this should not prevent your script from working, but Google recommends that you remove it.
2. Add an API key to your url with the `key=` parameter if you have one, or create and add one if you do not. This is probably your main issue. You can click the "GET A KEY" link [here](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/) in the upper right of the page.

Also, you may find the [error documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages) helpful when debugging these messages.

Comment: I added the key. input box is active but it is comming ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: @varunsharma try adding `&callback=initialize" async defer` to your script tag where you load the JS library (not the quote to close the `src` property and then the space separated values). This is how it is done in Google's tutorials.